# Android - How to improve performance of Image translation with alpha masking?

Tags: android, performance, canvas, alpha, multi-touch

I have this code that I call on each touch event that render an alpha masked bitmap:

...

```
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        Bitmap bleed = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.bleed);
        Bitmap photoBG = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.photo_bg);
        Bitmap mask = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.mask);
        Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(bleed.getWidth(), bleed.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);


        canvas.setBitmap(result);
        Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(photoBG, 0, 0, paint);
        canvas.drawBitmap(selectedImage, matrix, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.DST_IN));

        canvas.drawBitmap(mask, 0, 0, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bleed, 0, 0, paint);


        myImageView.setImageBitmap(result);
        bleed.recycle();
        mask.recycle();
        img.invalidate();

    }
```

...
The result image is ok but when I drag the image around, the performance is really slow, I've attached an explanatory image and my app screen capture (Note: the background is gray at the app).

[image]

Should I stick to this code (drawing on a canvas) or is there a better way achieving my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating 4 bitmaps on every touch, that's your performance issue. These are very expensive calls (especially the decode*() calls.) Create/load the btimaps only once :)

Comment: Right, what was I thinking ... I'll try and let you know

Comment: You can create/decode the `bleed`, `photoBG` and `mask` only once, before the first touch event. You do not even need to create `result` in every event, create it once before the first touch event and clear it (fill with black) on every invocation.

Comment: OK, The performance is much much better now, but it is still not as smooth as I wish it to be. If I was going to write something like that from scratch, what would be the right approach?